# How do I copy a row and split one of the columns based on certain criteria in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table of of 250k worth of data and out of this data I have 1000 rows that have the same data in every column bar one reference column which is different. The following is an example:

```
Name   | Tel_No     | Post_Code | Ref_No
Damian | 7900123456 | ME1 2BC   | 12345678 1234567891234
Graeme | 7900789012 | ME1 2DE   | 12 345 5678901234567
Sarah  | 7900456789 | ME1 2FG   | 90123456 890123456789
```

Now what I would like to do is for every row where the reference has an 8 digit number then a space and then a 13 digit number, I would like to copy this row but split the ref_no so that I have one row with the 8 digit ref_no and 1 with the 13 digit.

In the above example, the code should only work with the first line as Graeme doesn't meet this criteria as ref_no has 2 digits then a space therefore the code should fail straightaway. For Sarah the code will fail as the ref_no for the 2nd part only has 12 digits rather than 13. For Graeme and Sarah their data will still stay in the single rows with the ref_no they have.

I am guessing this has got to be done with regular expressions to find a matching pattern, unfortunately I haven't attempted any code as yet as again its new to me and the copying of the row has threw me out slightly as not done something like this before hence would love some advice on the best practices to move this forward.

Btw this is how it should look like in the table (I do have an auto ID column so the new rows will have new IDs assigned as well):

```
Name   | Tel_No     | Post_Code | Ref_No
Damian | 7900123456 | ME1 2BC   | 12345678
Damian | 7900123456 | ME1 2BC   | 1234567891234
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 04/02/2020 -----------------------

Apologies for the delay, unfortunately not been too well. Thanks guys for all your responses. Yunnosch, Wiktor, Rob as requested the following is my create table and insert statements and exactly what I am looking for just to make it a lot more clearer as to what I am asking. Apologies should have included at the start.

Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "BU_TABLE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "TEL_NO" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "POST_CODE" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "REF_NO" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "TABLE1_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
;
```

The reason I have set the Tel_No and the Ref_No column as Varchar2 is because of the spaces as when numbers have spaces then a) it will prompt a Invalid Number error b) Tel_No at the moment with the example data doesn't have this issue but as more data is added I might have this issue going forward.

My Insert Statements:

```
Insert into BU_TABLE (ID,NAME,TEL_NO,POST_CODE,REF_NO) values (1,'Damian','7900123456','ME1 2BC','12345678 1234567891234');
Insert into BU_TABLE (ID,NAME,TEL_NO,POST_CODE,REF_NO) values (2,'Graeme','7900789012','ME1 2DE','12 345 5678901234567');
Insert into BU_TABLE (ID,NAME,TEL_NO,POST_CODE,REF_NO) values (3,'Sarah','7900456789','ME1 2FG','90123456 890123456789');
```

Now what I would like is for the BU_TABLE to stay as it is, with the raw data. I would like to create another table of the back of this table to split out the Ref_No, so where I have a sequence of 8 numbers, a space and then 13 numbers. Wherever this pattern occurs I would like to duplicate the row, create a new ID (next available) and give me the following:

What I would like:

```
Name   | Tel_No     | Post_Code | Ref_No
Damian | 7900123456 | ME1 2BC   | 12345678
Damian | 7900123456 | ME1 2BC   | 1234567891234
```

The rows where the required code did not find the sequence, the rows of data will stay the same in the table so my final table will look like this:

Final Table

```
ID | Name   | Tel_No     | Post_Code | Ref_No
2 | Graeme | 7900789012 | ME1 2DE   | 12 345 5678901234567
3 | Sarah  | 7900456789 | ME1 2FG   | 90123456 890123456789
4 | Damian | 7900123456 | ME1 2BC   | 12345678
5 | Damian | 7900123456 | ME1 2BC   | 1234567891234
```

Hopefully that makes it a lot more clearer as to what I am trying to do.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query (consider using a SQLite toy database to provide a commandline-useable one).

Comment: Two rows for the two parts of the ref_no or two columns? The latter seems more likely in the situation you describe. Consider answering by showing the result you imagine. Make it up by just typing it manually.

Comment: Your description sounds like the desired result is `Damian | 7900123456 | ME1 2BC | 12345678` and `Damian | 7900123456 | ME1 2BC | 1234567891234`. But I think you might mean `Damian | 7900123456 | ME1 2BC | 12345678 | 1234567891234`.

Comment: Where do you want the result? As additional lines (pairs of lines) in the existing table? I think that would break the semantics of the ref_no column. Maybe as new lines (pairs of lines) in a separate table? That would allow to replace the single column ref_no by two columns ref_no8 and ref_no13.

Comment: Hi Yunnosch, thanks for your response. I would like 2 separate rows, just editing my post to show what final answer should look like. Thank you so much btw.

Comment: Make sure to indicate the original lines, do they remain? Are they deleted? Especially those lines ignored by the processing. Also please explain what you mean by "fail". Should the processing stop? Or just not process those lines?

Comment: The original table will remain as it is, I will be creating a staging table to move this part of the process so that I don't lose the original dataset. In terms of failure, where code doesnt meet criteria, it just moves onto the next row and so forth until no rows are available.

Comment: Please make a [mre] by showing a few lines of `create table ...` and `insert ...`, which make a tailored toy database .

Comment: ok will do, thanks

Comment: Are the value in ref_no guaranteed to be digits and blanks? I.e. is it reliable free of e.g. letters, special characters etc.?

Comment: How much of this can you do yourself? Can you e.g. at least create a new table and fill it with ALL the rows? Please show code for that. If that is already beyond you, then I am sorry to say that you are not asking a question focused on a programming problem, but instead ask for somebody to do the programming for you. In that case I recommend to first follow a few tutorials. Also, as for example visible in the answer below, providing a toy database is very important, to allow answerers to test their code and more easily avoid missing details of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr()` and `substr()` functions together for mutual comparison whether the splitted parts are equal. And then generate one more row for each row satisfying the `where` condition :

```
with t as
(
select regexp_substr(Ref_No,'[[:digit:]]{8}+') as Ref_No1_0,
       regexp_substr(Ref_No,'[^[:space:]]+$') as Ref_No2_0,
       substr(Ref_No,1,8) as Ref_No1_1 , substr(Ref_No,-13) as Ref_No2_1,
       t.*
  from tab t
)
select Name , Tel_No , Post_Code , 
       case when lvl = 1 then Ref_No1_0 
            when lvl = 2 then Ref_No2_0 end as Ref_No       
  from t
 cross join (select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 2) 
 where Ref_No1_0 = Ref_No1_1 
   and Ref_No2_0 = Ref_No2_1
```

Or directly use `regexp_like()`(together with `substr()`) functions in the `where` condition :

```
select Name , Tel_No , Post_Code , 
       case when lvl = 1 then substr(Ref_No,1,8) 
            when lvl = 2 then substr(Ref_No,-13) end as Ref_No
  from tab
 cross join (select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 2)   
 where regexp_like(substr(Ref_No,1,8),'[[:digit:]]{8}') 
   and regexp_like(substr(Ref_No,-13),'[[:digit:]]{13}')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ac5261b16b23fa9acd6856370811ca1c)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This method how you can split I will add full code:
This is for first 8 digit:

```
select substr(ref_no,0,8) from stack where instr(ref_no,' ') >= 9;
```

Full code =>

```
with 
tb_split8 as (
select Name, substr(ref_no,0,8) as split8 from stack where instr(ref_no,' ') >= 9),
tb_split13 as( 
select Name, substr(ref_no,10,13) as split13 from stack where instr(ref_no,' ',10) = 0 and length(substr(ref_no,10,13)) = 13)
select a.Name, Post_code, Tel_no, split8, split13 from stack a join tb_split8 b on a.Name = b.Name join tb_split13 c on b.Name = c.Name ;
```

I checked in Toad it is work.

[image]

Comment: This does not heed the 13 digit requirement.

Comment: It will also copy 8 non-blank characters which contain letters. I.e. this assumes that there are only digits. (I also think digit-only is guaranteed, but OP did not confirm.)

Comment: @Yunnosch Please try again I fixed some string.

Comment: Trying is hard since neither OP nor you provided a toy database. But I am pretty sure that your result only has one row where OP wants two.

Answer (score 0):

Even without regular expressions you can achieve getting two rows per the criteria you have as follows

```
with data
  as (
        select '12345678 1234567890123' as x /*This matches the 8<SPACE>13*/
         from dual
        union all
        select '1234567 1234567890123' as x
         from dual
     ) 
   ,criteria_data
    as (
        select t.*
               ,substr(x,1,instr(x,' ')) as first_part
               ,substr(x,instr(x,' ')+1,length(x)) as second_part
          from data t
         where length(x)-length(replace(x,' ',''))=1  /*Check for exactly one space*/
           and length(substr(x,1,instr(x,' ')))=8 /*check for first segment with 8 char*/
           and length(substr(x,instr(x,' ')+1,length(x)))=13 /*Check for second segment with 13 char length*/
       )
select a.*,case when lvl=1 then first_part when lvl=2 then second_part end as ref_no 
  from criteria_data a
  join (select level as lvl 
          from dual 
        connect by level<=2) b
    on 1=1
```